# How to establish fast communication between C# and python apps?

Tags: python, c#, .net, rest, tensorflow

I'm currently hosting a cnn neural network using tensorflow (a python app), now I want the 'frontend' to be made in .NET, the issue is, how do I integrate the neural network app (made in python, tensorflow) with the .NET gui app?

I thought about gRPC & REST however, those options seem slow & not perfect for what I intend (I will submit a lot of images to the neural network in a very short time)
so spamming REST requests & gRPC isn't that great

Basically, is there an easy and fast way to communicate between python and .NET (C#)?

Answer (score 1):

You can host Python in .NET process using [Python.NET](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet) (I am a co-maintainer).

I also develop a commercial TensorFlow binding for .NET: [Gradient](https://losttech.software/gradient.html). If you care about performance, it is [about 20% faster](https://github.com/losttech/Gradient-Perf) (at least for training) than [TensorFlow.NET](https://github.com/SciSharp/TensorFlow.NET), that ships with ML.NET.